# Django request Session not linking with logged in user model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-sessions

Despite calling authenticate and login for a valid username and password combination, when moving to another view the session fails to link with the user's user model. The model is instead an "AnonymousUser" and they cannot progress because it is required that they are a valid login user.

I've had a system that has worked well for quite some time (as I imagine everyone says before they have a problem...) To avoid having to add "require_login" decorator to every view, I have made a middleware that checks that the user is login and shall redirect them if they are not, to the login page.

This setup has been working for some time, but, recent changes to the user model has shown that users that were present pre-migration are no longer able to log in. What is baffling about this is that if they have their passwords updated via the django admin they can then access the site as normal

## authentication view

```py
import django.http
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, update_session_auth_hash, models as admin_models

from django.conf import settings

from .models import LoginAttempts

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define the alert to be given to the users if they have passed invalid user credentials
INVALID_LOGIN = {
    ...
}

LOCKED_ACCOUNT = {
    ...
}

def login_form(request):
    """ Return the login page """

    if request.POST: # Handle the form submission

        # Extract the user information + attempt to authenticate the user
        username, password = request.POST.get("username"), request.POST.get("password")
        log.debug("user '{}' attempting to log in".format(username))

        # Collect the user account corresponding to the username passed
        accountQuery = admin_models.User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if accountQuery.exists() and password is not None:
            userModel = accountQuery.first()
            if userModel.loginattempts.isLocked:
                log.debug("'{}'s' account has been locked due to repeated failed attempts".format(username))
                request.session["alerts"].append(LOCKED_ACCOUNT)
                return render(request, "login.html")
        else:
            log.debug("'{}'s username doesn't exist or no password provided".format(username))
            request.session["alerts"].append(INVALID_LOGIN)
            return render(request, "login.html")

        # Authenticate the user/password combination
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:  # The user has been authenticated, log them in and redirect to the index page
            log.debug("User {} has been verified - logging user in".format(username))
            login(request, user)
            userModel.loginattempts.attempts = 0
            userModel.save()
            return django.http.HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            log.debug("User {} failed to authenticate".format(username))
            request.session["alerts"].append(INVALID_LOGIN)
            userModel.loginattempts.attempts += 1
            if userModel.loginattempts.attempts >= 10: userModel.loginattempts.isLocked = True
            userModel.save()

    return render(request, "login.html")
```

## Middleware

```py
class RequireLogin:
    """ Require that the user be logging in to view the pages - avoiding the requirement
    to declare "@login_required" on all views
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response: callable):
        self.get_response = get_response  # Function passes the request through and fulfils and collects the generates response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path_info != settings.LOGIN_URL and not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        return self.get_response(request)
```

## The logs

If in the if statement of the middleware we add print statements to print the first condition (which I know must be true...) the request, the request user model, the request user model is_authenticated. we get the following reaction from the server:

[image: terminal]

Clearly, the function has determined that the user can be logged in and they are redirected to the index page, however, when they request the index page they are not identified as logged in by the session and are redirected back.

Here is an image of the Django session tokens, when attempting to log in for a single user, it genuinely only updates a single row:

[image: database]

To answer Daniel, here is the list of middleware in their order:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "ace_main.middleware.RequireLogin",
    "ace_main.middleware.RestrictedAccessZones",  # For certain areas - extra restriction - don't worry about this
    "ace_main.middleware.RemoveAlerts",  # Alert structure dequeue alerts already shown to the user
    "ace_main.middleware.UserLogging",  # track the user around the site 
]
```

Comment: Please show your middleware settings. Is RequireLogin after the AuthenticationMiddleware?

Comment: Yes, all custom middlewares are fired last @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to not "fully override auth process"... It's better to:

- use [`django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) (or custom form that inherits it)
- in your view simply use `if AuthenticationForm(data=self.request.POST, files=self.request.FILES).is_valid(): return django.http.HttpResponseRedirect(...)`. Or you can directly use `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` instead of your custom view function.
- To implement `isLocked` checking, tracking of `loginAttempts`, etc.: create a (custom auth backend)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend]:

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


class SophisticatedModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = super(self, SophisticatedModelBackend).authenticate(request, username=username, password=password, **kwargs)
        if user:
            user = self.check_user_locked(request, user, **kwargs)
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, INVALID_LOGIN)
        user = self.postprocess_login_attempt(request, user, username, **kwargs)
        return user

    def check_user_locked(self, request, user, **kwargs):
        if user.loginattempts.isLocked:
            # I'd also recommend to also use django.contrib.messages instead of changing request.session
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, LOCKED_ACCOUNT)
            return None
        return user

    def postprocess_login_attempt(self, request, user, username, **kwargs):
        if user:
            user.loginattempts.attempts = 0
            user.save()
        else:
            userModel = admin_models.User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
            if userModel:
                userModel.loginattempts.attempts += 1
                if userModel.loginattempts.attempts >= 10: userModel.loginattempts.isLocked = True
                userModel.save()

        return user
```

- Don't forget to set or update `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`

P.S. All of the above is more like a "best practice". If you just want to make your current code work, then you might try this:

```
 -            login(request, user)
 -            login(request, user, 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

Why this should work: `AuthenticationMiddleware` calls `auth.get_user`, which does:

```py
    try:
        user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
        backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

And `request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]` is set during `auth.login` to third argument which in your case eqauls `None`. All of this can be seen only in source of the django code, so it's better to use default `auth.LoginView` or `auth.AuthenticationForm` -> that way you will not miss anything critical.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to explain the best practices, I'm relatively new to Django so its a useful resource. I've added the reference to "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend" as you've suggested but unfortunately this hasn't fixed the issue :/ I'm not sure where the issue is, but, since I can create a new user or edit one of these old users, and then be able to login with this code just fine, I'm convinced that it's something to do with the migrations (or in subsequent attempts) the loading of the user fixtures. I'll implement your best practices to see if that helps

Comment: Sorry - that response may have obscured the message. That change didn't resolve the issue.